# nvm / node / npm: newer npm with node 12 than with node 14?

Tags: node.js, npm, version, node-modules, nvm

I'm using nvm to build libraries that require specific (different) Node versions.

When I do:
`nvm use 12`
I get:

> Now using node v12.21.0 (npm v8.14.0)

But when I do:
`nvm use 14`
I get:

> Now using node v14.18.1 (npm v6.14.15)

I'm very surprised to see an *older* npm version with a *newer* Node version. Is that the way it's supposed to be?

When I do `nvm use 14` I'd expect it uses the latest Node 14.x with whatever latest npm version is available for that Node version. Or am I misunderstanding how this works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node.js is distributed with a version of `npm`, but `npm` is still a seperate package that can be upgraded.

The distributed versions can be retrieved from [node release info](https://nodejs.org/download/release/index.json)

```
node      npm
v12.22.12 6.14.16
v14.20.0  6.14.17
v16.17.0  8.15.0
v18.9.0   8.19.1
```

`npm` can prompt you to upgrade when it detects an old version, and you will also to run into this instruction in the wild a fair bit:

```
npm install -g npm
```

This will grab whatever the latest version of `npm` is and is likely what happened in the `nvm 12` environment.

Sometimes moving to a new major version of `npm` can be a source of trouble for projects that have already been setup with a previous major `npm` release and some behaviour changes. CI tasks often have a `npm install -g npm` and one day they start falling over for what seems like no change. I've also seen npm drop support for an old version of node, so a `npm install -g npm` ends up with a broken npm.

If you want to keep a fixed major release, like v6 that Node 12 was release with, use:

```
npm install -g npm@^6
```

or to use a specific version

```
npm install -g npm@6.14.16
```

Comment: Thanks. So the fact that I have npm v8.14.0 in my Node 12 environment (when I use `nvm use 12`) means I probably upgraded to the latest npm version in the past (while in the 12 env)? And to avoid problems I'd better do `npm install -g npm@^6` in Node 12. And similarly, install the latest npm release in other Node versions picking the same major npm version as was originally shipped with that Node version? So `npm@^6` for Node 14, `npm@^8` for Node 16, etc. Do I interpret that correctly?

Comment: > means I probably upgraded to the latest npm version in the past (while in the 12 env)?
Yes, most likely

Comment: > And to avoid problems I'd better do?
npm v8 will be fine to run in Node 12.

Comment: The issue I was trying to highlight is that a `npm install -g npm` can affect projects that were already installed with an earlier major version of npm.  Also at some point, npm will drop support for Node 12, and a `npm install -g npm` can give you an unsupported version of npm. Neither of those should stop you from using node12/npm8 though.